# Mock FTP Connection Ready and Error event Node Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using the [FTP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp) library to establish the FTP connection to fetch the files from a specific location. I am writing a Node-Typescript-Express-based application. While creating the unit test cases, I am trying to mock the library to cover the code that is written under Ready event and Error Event. Below is the approach I am trying to use.

Code:

```
import * as Client from "ftp"
c = new Client()
c.on('ready', () => {
    c.list((err, list) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      //my code is here 
      c.end();
});
});
c.on("error",()=>{
   //my code is here
})
// connect to localhost:21 as anonymous
c.connect();
```

Test Case Approach 1:

```
import * as Client from "ftp";
c = new Client()
jest.spyOn(c,"connect")
jest.spyOn(c, "on")
  .mockImplementation()
  .mockResolvedValue((new EventEmitter).emit("ready"));
```

Test Case Approach 2:

```
import * as Client from "ftp";
c = new Client()
sinon.stub(Client.prototype, 'connect').withArgs().callsFake(()=>{
  (new EventEmitter).emit("ready"); 
});
```

Test Case Approach 3:

```
const connectMock = jest.fn()=>mockResult;

jest.mock("ftp",() =>({
connection:{
    cwd: jest.fn(),
    on: jest.fn(),
    connect: connectMock,
}
})) //not further
```

I need help if anyone can suggest me a valid approach or changes in approach that I have used so far. So that I can cover the code written for `ready`/`error` events in case of connection establishment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you get by using jestjs approach?

Comment: Nothing, coverage remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `ftp` package and its `Client` class.

Since your code is defined in the module scope, your code will be executed when the module is imported. We need to create the mock objects before importing the module.

In addition, I use `console.log` to represent your specific code implementation in the `error` event handler.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import Client from 'ftp';

const c = new Client();

c.on('ready', () => {
  c.list((err, list) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    c.end();
  });
});
c.on('error', () => {
  console.log('handle error');
});
c.connect();
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
const mc = {
  on: jest.fn(),
  list: jest.fn(),
  end: jest.fn(),
  connect: jest.fn(),
};
jest.mock('ftp', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => mc);
});

describe('67951757', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it('should handle ready', async () => {
    mc.on.mockImplementation(function (event, handler) {
      if (event === 'ready') {
        handler();
      }
      return mc;
    });
    mc.list.mockImplementation((callback) => {
      callback(null as any, []);
    });
    await import('./');
    expect(mc.on).toBeCalledWith('ready', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mc.on).toBeCalledWith('error', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mc.connect).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mc.list).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function));
    expect(mc.end).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should handle list error', async () => {
    mc.on.mockImplementation(function (event, handler) {
      if (event === 'ready') {
        handler();
      }
      return mc;
    });
    mc.list.mockImplementation((callback) => {
      callback(new Error('memory leak'));
    });
    await expect(() => import('./')).rejects.toThrow('memory leak');
    expect(mc.on).toBeCalledWith('ready', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mc.list).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function));
    expect(mc.end).not.toBeCalled();
  });

  it('should handle error', async () => {
    mc.on.mockImplementation(function (event, handler) {
      if (event === 'error') {
        handler();
      }
      return mc;
    });
    mc.list.mockImplementation((callback) => {
      callback(null as any, []);
    });
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    await import('./');
    expect(mc.on).toBeCalledWith('error', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mc.list).not.toBeCalled();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('handle error');
    logSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67951757/index.test.ts (9.59 s)
  67951757
    ✓ should handle ready (7869 ms)
    ✓ should handle list error (4 ms)
    ✓ should handle error (19 ms)

  console.log
    handle error

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:845:25)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.802 s
```

Comment: Thanks @slideshowp2, it worked for me to mock both the events. It was very helpful. Thanks again.